# How Can we index 100k+ posts efficiently?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-index

I'm trying to index a site on google. The site has 100k+ pages in it and keeps adding up every week.

What are the best ways to do it? The site is couple of months old and fairly doing good in google SERP.

There are SEO services, can they help with the indexing process?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. For example, in your sentence *Does the indexing services help?* please specify what service you are talking about. In your sentence *Is it possible to index them in a week?* are you talking about by a search engine??

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it clearly.

Comment: No one can make Google go any faster so do not bother with these services. You do not want to make Google mad. As well, for my site, I can see as much as 60,000 pages fetched in a day. How fast Google will fetch pages depends upon your sites freshness, errors, speed, popularity, etc. If your site is clean (free from issues) and fresh, it is possible that Google will fetch more than 100,000 pages per day. The up-shot is this. Leave Google alone. It can index the entire Internet in about 10 months which is remarkably fast. It will certainly know about links to your site fast enough.

Comment: Ah okay, I did a research. Even if change the crawl rate the google bot decide itself to crawl how much. Appreciate your answer.